# Django admin export issue

Tags: python, django

```
admin.site.register(RegistrationOTP)    
class RegistrationOTPResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = RegistrationOTP
        export_order = ('country','phone_number','otp','created_date','is_verified')

class RegistrationOTPAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = RegistrationOTPResource
```

here is models.py

```
class RegistrationOTP(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='otp_country', default=1)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=13)#, unique=True, validators=[phone_regex],
    otp = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_verified = models.CharField(choices=YES_OR_NO, default='no', max_length=10)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s : %s'% (self.phone_number, self.otp)
```

Here i am doing as per documentation but it is not showing export csv option in admin

Comment: it is commented..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class RegistrationOTPResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = RegistrationOTP
        fields = '__all__'
        export_order = ('id','country','phone_number','otp','created_date','is_verified')
```

try this, i guess due to missing fields section, it is not working

Comment: coming in my shell.  but not coming in django admin

Comment: is there anything to don inside views??

Comment: have you registered the modeladmin with the model class in the admin.py?

Comment: class RegistrationOTPAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = RegistrationOTPResource

Comment: is it?? or something else

Comment: no add this line after this line `admin.site.register(RegistrationOTP,RegistrationOTPAdmin)` and remove the other admin.site.register from the top

Comment: glad to help you bro, you can also give a thumbs up to the answer